# How to move Steam games on OS change (32-bit to 64-bit)

Tags: steam

I have found many questions regarding this on this Q&A Board. However, I am not only moving my games from Vista to 7, but also from 32-bit to 64-bit. I once had some trouble doing so using a backup (same account), hence the reason I ask. Are there known problems moving from x86 to x64 while using the same Steam files?

I wouldn't mind downloading my games again that much because I have a DL-Flatrate, it's just that I would have to download around 200GB, which would take around 3 days just using my bandwidth for Steam. Also, my provider probably won't be happy.

Comment: Although your question is different, I would give it the same answer as this one: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13158/can-i-download-steam-games-on-one-computer-mac-then-install-them-on-another-w/13615#13615

Comment: Th... three days?  Don't ever, ever talk to me about 'long' download times.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you need is `Steam.exe` and the `steamapps` folder. Move those into `C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam` and run `Steam.exe`. The application will redownload all of the steam files and will automatically detect all of your installed games in the steamapps folder. It's a really neat program actually.

As far as I know, Steam doesn't use 64-bit for the client or for the games, so you shouldn't run into any issues.

Comment: My roommate, neighbor and I use this so that only one of us downloads a copy, then we move it to the other machines ... and we have a mix of XP and 7, and haven't had any problems (I *think* one of the 7 machines is 64bit).

Answer (score 7):

For the past 4 years I've just moved the same Steam directory around to my other computers (or to a temporary drive when I do a reformat).

Occasionally you have to reinstall the Steam client over the old install, but this is, in my experiences, rare.

You should have absolutely no issues.

EDIT: Also remember that some of your save games get saved into your My Documents folder.  Don't forget those if you want your old saves!

Comment: +1 for mentioning save games. I wish games could save their data in a consistent location