# Can I restore a game from Mac to PC using steam backup/restore or by copying?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I have CSGO installed in my MacBook and I don't want to re-download at least the whole file. So I was thinking if it is possible to create a steam backup on my MacBook and restore the file on steam PC or by copying files from PC?

Is it possible for at least some file?

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/222792/can-i-copy-steam-game-files-from-a-mac-onto-a-pc?rq=1 duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the short answer is **NO** and **NO**.

In theory it's possible to reuse part of the files (textures, audios, etc), because this ones are common between the platforms, however the binaries are completely different and due the steam method of backup (the whole thing in one file) the hash will be different. it's more or less as you try to run a PS4 game into an XBOX.

You may be able to transfer the save games between platforms. But I don't think is the case of CSGO.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **YES** and I have tested it just now. Any way i'm accepting answer by Alexrgs as he said the right answer about backup and restoring.

**Steps to copy from PC to Mac**

- Copy the whole Counter-Strike Global Offensive folder from `Program Files (x86)/Steam/SteamApps/common` to `/Users/your_username/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common`
- Also copy `appmanifest_730` from `Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/` to `/Users/your_username/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/`
- Delete csgo.exe, /bin/ and /csgo/bin/. As far as I can see, these are the only os-specific files.
- Restart Steam and verify the game integrity in Steam. It should download about 50 mb worth of OSX-specific files.

Your game should work.